# jenkins git build does not merge

Tags: git, jenkins

Hi i configured the jenkins git to do a merge before build, but I always run into this error:

```
11:56:18 Merging Revision 45ed7eae4cdc71d348610819fa0bcbc6d511e99b (origin/features/maven) to /development, UserMergeOptions{mergeRemote='', mergeTarget='development', mergeStrategy='default', fastForwardMode='--ff-only'}
11:56:18  > /usr/bin/git rev-parse /development^{commit} # timeout=10
11:56:18 FATAL: Command "/usr/bin/git rev-parse /development^{commit}" returned status code 128:
11:56:18 stdout: /development^{commit}
11:56:18 
11:56:18 stderr: fatal: ambiguous argument '/development^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

the configuration looks like this:

[image]

before he can check out properly

I try to merge according to a pull request from a features/maven branch to development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not fill in the name of the repository. If I put origin in there it works

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the git merge locally which is good. And you are not pushing it to the remote. That's the problem. So please add the action `Git Publisher` in `Post-build Actions`. There will be options like, `Push Only If Build Succeeds` and `Merge Results`. Please check those and you can find some more options like `Branches`, `Tags`, `Notes` like that. Feel free to explore all those. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a solution to publish. But this otherwise has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: I forgot to mention about the `origin` in my solution. My bad. Anyway you got your solution right. :)